# Laravel 5.1 giving 404 Not Found except Homepage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a website set up on Laravel 5.1. It throws a 404 error on any page except the homepage. However, when I add index.php in the URL, it works. My site runs on a Ubuntu machine with Nginx as the web server.

**Loads fine:** mysite.com/index.php/dashboard

**Gives 404:** mysite.com/dashboard

**My .htaccess in the public folder:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your time and I would greatly appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

This is my Nginx conf:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name www.mysite.com;

# note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
root   /usr/share/web/site/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/web/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

  #  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
   
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

    include        fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A .htaccess is for Apache. It will not work on Nginx.

Try this in your nginx site configuration (taken from the Laravel documentation.)

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: I have that in my file. See above.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't really use Nginx that often so I don't think I can help you further.